# access) How can I match the name in the column from a new input data?

Tags: sql, ms-access, match, ms-access-2010

I have a "Name" column with a format of "last name first name", 
however if there is a different format of name column in a new data which should be matched to my original data, how can I make it to be matched automatically??

For example ,

I have :

```
Name          
Jane Carr 
Tony Kwon
```

and the new data has :

```
Name
Ms. Jane or Jane, Carr 
Mr. Tony or Tony, Kwon
```

how can these two names can be automatically  matched to my original data of Jane Carr and Tony Kwon?

Comment: Name fields are really hard to use as keys or to link tables - there are just too many inconsistencies.  Do you have any kind of ID field you can use instead?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 has a new feature called 'Temporal Tables' that could potentially solve this issue.  But you would have to be willing to use the newest version of SQL Server 2016: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use 'like' to match the strings if the entire string is unknown in the where clause after the column name.

```
    select * from table_name where name like '%jane carr%';
```

This is a wild card. 
% before the string means - search all which has name ending with mentioned string.

% after the string means - search all which has name starting with mentioned string.

% before and after means - search all which has matching string.